# When updating a CloudFormation stack, what happens to any code or data that's stored within the stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm currently learning AWS CloudFormation, and I came across the update feature that CloudFormation has. My understanding is that since CloudFormation is infrastructure as a code, updating a stack in CloudFormation will update the infrastructure within the stack (i.e. changing an EC2 instance from T2.nano to T2.micro). However, I couldn't find any information on what happens to anything that's stored in the stack. For example, if you have a bucket stored in S3 Standard and you update the stack to have the bucket in S3 Infrequent Access instead, does this move the bucket into Infrequent Access or does this make a copy of the bucket in the new Infrequent Access and delete the original? Would this be similar to other services within the stack (such as changing an EC2 instance from T2.nano to T2.micro affecting any configurations done within the EC2 instance)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question

Comment: @luk2302 Ah my bad then. So am I correct to assume that objects won't be transferred over to the new instance? Would any changes that may have happened between the start of the first instance and the update to the new instance also not be transferred over?

Answer (score 0):

Change of `InstanceType` will lead to "some interruptions" as explained in the [AWS::EC2::Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-instancetype).

This means that your instance will be stopped, its type will be changed and started again. There is **no replacement**, so all your data will be preserved.